# I am trying to write a prog to execute commands in unix from java using jsch api

Tags: eclipse, jsch

I took a sample program from google and executed  and i got the expected result but the program did not terminate automatically and i manually terminated in eclipse every time.

I have closed channel,session ,input stream.

In my program i use byte array to get console inputs and i could not close that.

any help is appreciated.

**Code ran in eclipse:**

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;  
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;  
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;  
public class SSHConnectionJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String host = "10.140.20.23"; ///custom server
        String user = "demo";
        String password = "password";
    String scriptname = "/home/ababu/create.sh";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(scriptname);
    sb.append(" ");
    sb.append("T12345");
    String command = sb.toString();
                try {
            Properties config = new Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            // Create a JSch session to connect to the server
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig(config);
            // Establish the connection
            session.connect();
            System.out.println("Connected...");
            ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
            channel.setCommand(command);
            channel.setErrStream(System.err);
            channel.setInputStream(System.in);
            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
            channel.connect();
            byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
            while (true) {
                while (in.available() > 0) {
                    int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                    if (i < 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                }
                if (channel.isClosed()) {
                    System.out.println("Exit Status: "
                            + channel.getExitStatus());
                    break;
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
            System.out.println("DONE!!!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Inside /home/ababu/create.sh:
mkdir $1

Comment: Let me see your code, then I can help you.

Comment: @Jakob added my code.

Comment: @AadharshAdi You have to edit your answer and add all your code to the question. It is really hard to read code from an image.

Comment: Added my complete code instead of image.Any Help is Appreciated.

Comment: You should tell us with an [edit] how you are running this code. Also, remember that Eclipse has a built-in debugger. Learn debugging earlier rather than later.

Comment: @jdv i am running my code in eclipse.

Comment: So tell us one what statement does an execution stop.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl execution stops in the last sysout statement printing  done.

Comment: **In** the statement? Do it does not even print "DONE!!!"? Are you sure it does not stop in `session.disconnect`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl it prints DONE and then the execution hangs without termination

Comment: If you add another `System.out.println` after that, will is display?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yes it will.

Comment: So it's not true that *"execution stops in the last sysout statement printing done"* - What is a callstack, if you pause execution while the program hangs?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl i am getting -c:/program files/java/jre8/bin/javaw.exe(date)

Comment: channel.setInputStream(System.in); InputStream in = channel.getInputStream(); while (in.available() > 0) {...}  That looks fishy to me.
If I understand correctly 'in == System.in', you read indefinitely your own standard input. You should drop the 'printf' debugging and attach with eclipse debugger.